# How do I change a material color in this file?

Tags: color, color-management

I want to change the color of pages and hardcover from black to white, but I am unable to do it without giving it emission (?).

[image]

Dumb noob question, looking for quick smart answers.

Comment: It's made with Geometry Nodes modifier so materials are assigned in the modifier's node tree. It would be an impressive node tree for a noob. Where did you get the book? Maybe it comes with instructions?

Comment: It's a sample project, I didn't develop the node structure

Comment: Can you pack the images into the Blend file and share it again? - File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender. - The materials are quite straightforward by the look of them in the shader editor but we'd need to see the images that are used for the complete picture.

Comment: Cannot upload it on the reglular uploader, too heavy, here's the link:
https://we.tl/t-dJ2CjeSkyI